# Does Mysql maintain any reference to its transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, database

By using Transaction reference or id, Can I rollback committed transactions in future? OR any other better way to rollback a set of mysql queries after being saved in table.
Kind courtesy to all.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is this for data recovery or just arbitary operations within your applicaiton?

Comment: Why would you need to rollback committed changes? The whole purpose of using transactions is so you can make sure everything works as expected _before_ you commit it. When it's saved, it's saved. Please include an example of the problem you're trying to solve and we might be able to come up with some good suggestions.

Comment: If further alterations have been made to the records in the transaction - what do you do?  Do you roll back the other changes - which means rolling back other transactions?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Eg: let Transaction#1 includes n number of queries (query#1=insert xyz, query#2=update xyz), I need these db changes to be reverted by rolling back Transaction#1....Do mysql save its transactions in such a way?

Comment: The simple answer is no. Once a transaction is committed, all information about it is discarded. The database doesn't maintain running snapshots anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Sir, but is there any other way to achieve same?

Comment: Nothing built into the database, you'll have to design your own system for saving the database contents so you can revert it. It seems like this would be pretty complicated to do in a general way.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, for now I m doing this with update log, But many conditions yet to be added in code...By d way Thanks for ur precious time.

Comment: @WC2 What problem are you trying to solve by rolling back the database? Perhapps there are other alternative suggestions to provide.

Comment: @Scuzzy ..I have implemented invoicing module for a shop ...where data entry guyz fill wrong details and contact me to remove particular invoice. Revert back all  details.